# Building and running Android Bluetooth stack on linux?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, stack

I tried to compile and run the android bluetooth protocol stack on linux. I followed the instructions from google's official link (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/), but it didn't work.
I think the document has not been updated for a long time, and the Bluetooth code and compilation dependency have version changes.
When I finally executed ./build.py, I reported an error.

```
ERROR at //common-mk/proto_library.gni:80:34: No value named "proto_force_optimize_speed" in scope "use"
    } else if (use.fuzzer || use.proto_force_optimize_speed) {
                                 ^-------------------------
See //external/proto_logging/stats/enums/bluetooth/BUILD.gn:18:1: whence it was called.
proto_library("libbt-platform-protos-lite") {
^--------------------------------------------
See //bt/system/BUILD.gn:137:5: which caused the file to be included.
    "//external/proto_logging/stats/enums/bluetooth:libbt-platform-protos-lite",
    ^--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 808, in <module>
    build.build()
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 556, in build
    self._target_all()
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 524, in _target_all
    self._target_prepare()
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 413, in _target_prepare
    self._gn_configure()
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 369, in _gn_configure
    self.run_command('configure', gn_args)
  File "/home/ljj/fluoride/Bluetooth/./build.py", line 278, in run_command
    raise Exception("Return code is {}".format(rc))
Exception: Return code is 1
```

Trace the bulid.py source code. When process = subprocess.Popen(args, cwd=cwd, env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) is executed, args is printed.
The args is ['gn', 'gen',' --root=/home/ljj/.floss/staging ',' --args=platform_subdir="bt" cc="clang" cxx="clang++" ar="llvm-ar" pkg_config="pkg-config" clang_cc=true clang_cxx=true OS="linux" sysroot="/" libdir="/usr/lib" build_root="/home/ljj/.floss/output" platform2_root="/home/ljj/.floss/staging" libbase_ver="NOT-INSTALLED" enable_exceptions=false external_cflags=[] external_cxxflags=["-DNDEBUG","-I/usr/include/"] enable_werror=false use={asan=false coverage=false cros_host=false fuzzer=false msan=false profiling=false tcmalloc=false test=true ubsan=false android=false bt_nonstandard_codecs=false clang=true} ',' /home/ljj/.floss/output/out/Default '].

I don't know how to solve this problem. Have any experts ever encountered similar problems? How was it solved?